# Should the words "much needed" be hyphenated or not?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

Here's an example of what I mean:

"It's time for some much needed rest and relaxation."

Or should it be:

"It's time for some much-needed rest and relaxation."

Comment: A hyphen is not normally required for adverb-adjective combinations, but you see it a lot anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Noun phrases are normally hyphenated when used as adjectives. For example:

> These is some oak panels.
>
> This is my oak-pannelled wardrobe.
>
> This is green cotton
>
> This is my green-cotton sweater.

Hence you would say

> This is a much-needed holiday.

That being said, English is somewhat relaxed in this regard, and both would be widely understood and are both widely used by English speakers:

[image: http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=much+needed+holiday%2C+much-needed+holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=]

Comment: Sorry, but *much* is not functioning as an adjective in this sentence, but an adverb. You would not write "This is my very-green sweater," would you?

Comment: No, but then "green" is not a participle. "Much-needed" looks to me like a participle and modifier being combined into an adjective. In that situation we often use the hyphen. You would, for example, write "this is my well-intentioned friend".

Comment: @MετάEd: So you'd write "sorely-needed" in front of a noun? In AmE we usually leave the hyphen out unless it is sorely needed for clarity.

Comment: @Robusto: With normal adverbs, nobody uses hyphens. On certain special adverbs, however, opinions vary—like *much*, *well*, *fast*, etc., which are perhaps less easily identified as adverbs at first sight. I expect style books to be split (I don't have a problem with either variant myself).